# Pre-Count is SQL0572N Package "NULLID.SQLC2O28" is inoperative

Tags: db2, websphere

Occasionally when I attempt to run Stored Procedure’s to load data, in my dev environment, I receive this error:

Pre-Count is SQL0572N  Package "NULLID.SQLC2O28" is inoperative. SQLSTATE=51028

Does anyone have ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [DB2 v11.1 Bind File and Package Name List](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-v111-bind-file-and-package-name-list) link, the `SQLC2O28` package is a part of the `db2clpcs.bnd` bind file of the Db2 11.1.4.4 client.
This bind file is listed in the `db2ubind.lst` list, which should be bound from your 11.1.4.4 client to the database, if you want to run some command / utilities using your client.

If some of these packages are inoperative, it's better not to bind them manually, since it may be quite a long journey, but ask someone with an appropriate authorization to bind whole `db2ubind.lst` from your (or from some another one at the same version and fixpack) client to the database:

```
db2 connect to mydb ...
db2 "bind .../@db2ubind.lst blocking all grant public"
```

Answer (score 0):

A package will become inoperative when an object on which it depends becomes altered or dropped. In a development environment it may be common for objects to become dropped, altered, recreated etc.

Documentation [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql0500-sql0749#sql0572n)

You can either rebind the specific package concerned, or run a tool to rebind all packages that are inoperative. In your case, if you are able to use the command-line to connect with suitable authority `db2 rebind package NULLID.SQLC2O28`, but keep in mind that there may be multiple packages that are inoperative, hence the `db2bind` command might be helpful, [doclink](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-db2rbind-rebind-all-packages).

An example (with a different package number) is in this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql0572n-package-nullidsqluah19-inoperative-bind-error), and the same principle applies

The auth-ID (i.e. the user with which you connect to the database) needs to have appropriate authorisation and permissions in the database, for the rebind actions to complete successfully, otherwise they will throw permission exceptions.